# Problems handling QTextEdit event()

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have developed a gui in Qt Designer, that among other things, displays a QTextEdit widget.

I need to handle the user entering the certain key combinations (TAB key, SHIFT + ENTER and SHIFT + RETURN so far) in such a way that it doesn't display those characters in the QTextEdit widget and implements some custom functionality.

I have created a handler to detect *keyReleaseEvent*s, but that seems to be too late to prevent tabs, carriage returns etc. getting displayed, so then I tried handling *keyPressEvent*s, but that doesn't seem to work at all. From what I've read online, people are saying that the *keyPressEvent* is getting consumed by the widget and so never gets propagated up to the gui. I don't know enough about QTextEdit widgets to say if that's correct, but for now I'm assuming it is.

So then I tried this in the class `__init__` method for the gui (I have left out the check for the RETURN key to keep the code short below:

`self.textEdit.event = self.eventX`

Here's the code for the eventX method:

`def eventX(self, event):
    if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and event.key() == Qt.Key_Tab:
        print 'CODE WINDOW: Tab pressed'
        self.textEdit.insertPlainText(QString('|    |'))
        self.textEdit.update()
        event.accept()
        return True
    elif event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and (event.key() == Qt.Key_Enter) and event.modifiers() & Qt.ShiftModifier:
        print 'CODE WINDOW: Shift pressed with Enter'
        self.submitCode()
        self.textEdit.update()
        event.accept()
        return True
    else:
        event.ignore()
        return QWidget.event(self, event)`

This is where things get strange. The code above will sort of work if I have specified that:
`verticalScrollBarPolicy = Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded` 
for the QTextEdit widget, except that it won't actually display the characters in the widget, but it does seem to handle the TAB and SHIFT-ENTER/SHIFT-RETURN keys being pressed?

And then, if I set `verticalScrollBarPolicy = Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn`, the eventX method seems to get completely ignored!

This is driving me crazy at this stage. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE: Based on the information from MDURANT, I now have the code below that works for me:

`def handleEditorKeyPress(self, event):
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_Tab:
        # My custom code goes here.
        event.accept()
        return
    elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Enter and event.modifiers() & Qt.ShiftModifier:
        # My custom code goes here.
        event.accept()
        return
    elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Return and event.modifiers() & Qt.ShiftModifier:
        # My custom code goes here.
        event.accept()
        return
    else:
        event.ignore()
        return QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self.textEdit, event)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of capturing key events. In this case, I simply pass the event through to another identical widget, but in general, you can set the event function to anything

```
class win(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.box = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.box)
        self.ed1 = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.ed2 = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.ed1.keyPressEvent = self.ed2.keyPressEvent
        self.ed1.keyReleaseEvent = self.ed2.keyReleaseEvent
        self.box.addWidget(self.ed1)
        self.box.addWidget(self.ed2)
```

See the documentation of the event:     http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#keyPressEvent